# Creating a simple messaging App on iOS and keep getting the same error

Tags: swift, debugging, error-handling

Im Creating a simple messaging App on iOS and keep getting the same error

The Line of Code that the error keeps popping up in is this line

```
self.listOfChatInfo.append(Chat(userName: username!, text: text!, datePosted: "\(postDate!)"))
```

The error that keeps popping up is

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Im only starting out and this was from an online small video tutorial so no help from their end at all.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: maybe post a link to the view

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `username`, `text` and `postDate` is not nil.

You can use this code to avoid runtime error.

```
let userName = username ?? ""
let chatText = text ?? ""
let date = postDate ?? ""

self.listOfChatInfo.append(Chat(userName: userName, text: chatText, datePosted: date))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be ok.

```
let element = Chat(userName: username!, text: text!, datePosted: "\(postDate!))
self.listOfChatInfo.append(element)
```